# Exercise: Uniform Boundedness Principle and Double dual

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $(x_{n})$ be a sequence in $X$. Show that if the sequence $f(x_{n})$ is bounded for every $f \in X^{\ast}$, then there exists $C > 0$ such that $\|x_{n}\| < C$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Hint: Consider each $x_{n}$ as an element of $X^{\ast\ast}$ and use the  Uniform Boundedness Principle.

I only know that I must take the canonical mapping $J: X \rightarrow X^{\ast \ast}$.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an easy consequence of U.B.P. applied to the normed space $X^*$ and the set of operators $S:={J(x_n); n\in N}$. Indeed, for every $f \in X^*$ there is a $C_f$ such that $|y(f)|\leq C_f$ for all $y\in S$. Applying the U.B.P we have that there is $C$ so that $\Vert y\Vert\leq C$ for all $y\in S$. But every y of S is of the form $y=J(x_n)$, and thus $\Vert y\Vert=\Vert J y_n\Vert=\Vert x_n\Vert$. And the result follows

Comment: Thank you, zap. I was drowning in a glass of water.